# How to use concurrent.futures in a complex multi-file/module project?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, concurrent.futures

The way it requires and uses the `__main__` namespace seems confusing and problematic when trying to create functions that can be called from another module or file that use concurrent.futures...

How exactly is it supposed to be used? Let's say for example I have a module that will process some input using concurrent. I import that into my main program or some other module, but then calling the imported function, it want's to use the `__main__` namespace of the main program or module it got imported into (and of course want's to spawn the new processes running the current python file instead of the one I wanted).

Is it possible to call functions from another file or module that use concurrent, taking your arguments but executing with the imported functions file and namespaces?

Comment: `concurrent.futures` is built on top of the `multiprocessing` library, which also has these requirements. Your question seems a bit unclear to me.. Are you asking how to properly write a library/module that utilizes `multiprocessing`?

Comment: Basically if you write a library that uses multiprocessing, you must instruct users of the library to only call functions that will result in child processes being created inside the protection of `if __name__ == "__main__":`. It is simply a requirement for multiprocessing using "spawn". ([Here's](https://newbedev.com/workaround-for-using-name-main-in-python-multiprocessing) a little write-up with more details on the matter)

Comment: basically for any script to be multiprocessing safe, It shouldn't do anything that could result in a child process being created on import rather than when it is executed as a script. `__name__` is only equal to `"__main__"` when you execute a file as a script. if it is imported, `__name__` will be different (it's a special variable python creates for you on startup).

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I'm trying to write a module that uses multiprocessing (that part is fine). But I'm running into issues with then importing and using the module because of how it had to import `__main__`.

Comment: could you create a minimal example that reproduces the problem you're having, and edit your question with it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.